# Is there a gem to generate a diagram from SCSS files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, sass, diagram

Our application is using a very, very complex system of .scss files for styling. We have multiple imports and includes, spread over several folders. Now we want to simplify that. But before we start, it would be very handy to have a tool to generate the current structure as a diagram.

Like the gems you can use to generate a ERD from your Rails models.

Are there any known tools?

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I misunderstand your question, but you can get a quick view of your directory structing using the `tree` command in Windows/Unix (you may need to install `tree` with your favorite package manager depending on your distro. Mac os X users can install `tree` using [homebrew](https://brew.sh).

Example output

`cd path/to/project`

`tree`

```
├── test
│   ├── 1
│   │   └── file$.scss
│   ├── 2
│   │   └── file$.scss
│   ├── 3
│   │   └── file$.scss
│   ├── 4
│   │   └── file$.scss
│   └── 5
│       └── file$.scss
└── test.txt
```

Obviously, this is not a rails specific solution; if i've missed the point hopefully others will be able to provide a more rubyesque option.